# 18.04 Wifi Network Help

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04

I am trying to find the bottleneck in my ubuntu 18.04's wifi. My router is putting out speeds of ~150mbps but my computer (with a tp-link adapter rated for 150) WAS only showing 25mb in speedtests.
Then I made the dumb choice to try to install better adapters. So I followed the tips from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNEB1JwkAG4&t=186s) which basically installs the driver for the adapter I think. But now my speeds are showing more like 10mbps. I'd really appreciate help getting to the bottom of this.

```
    *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: enp6s0
       version: 0c
       serial: e0:d5:5e:dd:39:7c
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp aui bnc mii fibre 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:36 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fe700000-fe700fff memory:f0300000-f0303fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@3:4
       logical name: wlx503eaa8c0598
       serial: 50:3e:aa:8c:05:98
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu ip=192.168.86.63 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Comment: More info is needed: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos.

Comment: I think I have added more info. its r8188eu driver.

Comment: Here is a pastebin of the info https://pastebin.com/n9pd78eS

Comment: It looks ok. Router vendors like to make crazy claims about their products speed, but in reality, 150mbps, or 72mbps in your case, are maximum theoretical throughputs under ideal lab conditions. They are never really achievable, let alone outside the lab. There are also factors like interference, apartment walls and distance. In short, if you've ever expected to get ~150mbps speeds, it was unrealistic, and you'd have to adjust expectations.

Comment: My phone and other laptop are getting about 75mbps when I speedtest them